# Where to put a before_filter shared between multiple controllers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module, before-filter

I have multiple controllers that all use an identical before_filter. In the interests of keeping things dry, where should this method live so that all the controllers can use it? A module doesn't seem like the right place, though I'm not sure why. I can't put it in a base class as the controllers already have different superclasses.

Comment: *A module doesn't seem like the right place*. Why not?

Comment: @1ndivisible you should accept nwwatson's answer below.

Comment: You are correct. Slipped through the cracks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about putting your before_filter and method in a module and including it in each of the controllers. I'd put this file in the lib folder.

```
module MyFunctions

  def self.included(base)
    base.before_filter :my_before_filter
  end

  def my_before_filter
    Rails.logger.info "********** YEA I WAS CALLED ***************"
  end
end
```

Then in your controller, all you would have to do is

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  include MyFunctions
end
```

Finally, I would ensure that lib is autoloaded. Open config/application.rb and add the following to the class for your application.

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: Don't forget to make the filter method `protected` in the module if it isn't meant to be publicly facing.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this can be done.

```
Class CommonController < ApplicationController
  # before_filter goes here
end

Class MyController < CommonController
end

class MyOtherController < CommonController
end
```

Comment: My controllers have different superclasses so this isn't an option.

Comment: I prefer @KulbirSaini's approach, by that way not only before_filters , I will be able to set the layouts also. But of course if your controllers have different super classes, module approach would be the choice

Answer (score 3):

Place the `before_filter` in the shared superclass of your controllers. If you have to go so far up the inheritance chain that this winds up being `ApplicationController`, and you are forced to apply the `before_filter` to some controllers it shouldn't apply to, you should use `skip_before_filter` in those specific controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :require_user
end

# Login controller shouldn't require a user
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_user
end

# Posts requires a user
class PostsController < ApplicationController

end

# Comments requires a user
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this feels wrong. I have 12 controllers and 4 of them use this before_filter. That's a lot of skip_before_filter in the others.

Comment: Then you're out of other options. Place the method and `before_filter` in a module.

Comment: Fair enough. Was just interested to see if I was missing something obvious. I haven't seen skip_before_filter before so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it is common to all controllers, you may put it in the application controller. If not, you can create a new controller and make it the superclass of them all and put the code in it.