# before_action for specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      before_action :test, only: [:index]

      def test
          ap 'test'
      end
    end
```

The above is run before every single index action, be it dogs#index or cats#index or rabbits#index. How should I get it to execute just before cats#index and rabbits#index?

I want to test to be exectuted before actions in many controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move your call into the controller you want it to run in.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # nothing here!

  def test
    # ...
  end
end

class CatsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :test, only: [:index]
end

class RabbitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :test, only: [:index]
end
```

Comment: If there is a sensible sub-category of controller that this action applies to, you could introduce that to the inheritance chain: `class FluffyPetsController < ApplicationController` and `class CatsController < FluffyPetsController`

Comment: ^ Good addition. Some circumstances may also call for a module which mixes in this call to `before_action`. (`class CatsController < ApplicationController; include FluffyPets; end;`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940253/where-to-put-a-before-filter-shared-between-multiple-controllers gives an example of the module-based solution

Answer (score 9):

You can skip this method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :test, only: [:index]

  def test
    p 'test'
  end
end

class DogsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :test
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple actually

Create before_action in application_controller and check `if:` that incoming request is for concerned_controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_create :assign_setting, only: :create, if: :registration_controller?

  def registration_controller?
    params["controller"] == "registrations"
  end
 
  def assign_settings
    # your code
    puts "settings applied"
  end
end
```