# Any difference when after_action in application controller or in model controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are `orders` & `order_items` controller in our Rails 4 app. We would like to add a `after_action` to log after a `action`.

```
  after_action :info_logger
```

The `after_action` is intended for both controllers. We can either add the `after_action` in both `orders_controller` & `order_items` controller. Or add it only to `application_controller` which works for both controllers. Is there any tech difference between adding `after_action` to `orders & order_items` controller and `application` controller (after_action in application covers both controllers)?

Comment: Please see the discussion at the *[Where to put a before_filter shared between multiple controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940253/where-to-put-a-before-filter-shared-between-multiple-controllers)* question. I personally would vote for a module that has both the action and the `after_action` defined in it and that is included from both controllers. This makes the code DRY but explicit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What we find in degug is that the `afer_action` in application results in more logging (some may be duplicate logging) than it is in model controller. If you care about duplicate logging, then it is better to leave the `after_action` in model controller.

Answer (score 0):

As you see that in general every controller is inherited from application controller.

So if you write some code in application controller than it is available to all child controller like orders and order_items in your case.